# What does the word "underlying" mean here?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, adjectives

Please help me figure out the meaning of the word "underlying" in the following sentence:

*After the **underlying** app platform appeared on a well-known TV show, a police officer reached out to the developer to ask about implementing the system in their department.*

For some context, the said platform became much more popular later and added more features. Does the word "underlying" mean "basic" or "initial" here?

Comment: The word "underlying" may be unnecessary or even incorrect. If you include a link to the context for that quote, it would be easier to understand.

Answer (score 1):

It appears to be a reference to a program that implemented a capability of interest to the police officer.  Since the excerpt refers to the application platform, but not to anything that uses it, the thing that uses the application platform as a foundation cannot be discerned from the context.